# MySQL - Date Column Format

Tags: mysql, date, format, date-format

I am familiar with `DATE_FORMAT` function which can display the the record from my date field in the format specified. However, I would like to create a table with a date field that only accepts my format.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
f_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
l_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
date_hired DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Inserting a record with a date_hired value of '2013-03-01' will be inserted as '1/03/2013 12:00:00 AM' which is far from my expected result (I would like the format the way it was inserted). Any feedback? Did I miss something?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Format it in your query using `DATE_FORMAT`. The `date` type itself doesn't have any type and is stored numerically

Comment: Hi @zerkms, I'm new with MySQL. What do you mean by 'stored numerically'?

Comment: ignore it an read the whole comment. And check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format additionally

Comment: Date is saved in numeric format not only in MySQL but in most of databases. Generally any date is difference of time with a predefinded date from history. So lets say there is db with 1/1/1900 as their predifined historic date as base. And now if u want to save 1/1/2013, it will internally calculate difference of days from historic date to your date and would convert it in millisec (or ticks) and will save the final number in db. Reverse process would be done when u want read date field from db. Just before displaying the result to the user it shows format based on db settings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't change the format during table create, you can change the format of date for displaying user by using you programming logic like if you are using PHP as your server side language the you can convert it your desired format.

Comment: I would have upvoted this correct answer if it had a couple of examples, and a reference to PHP date formats.